# Pandas: idempotent/force join between dataframes with column overlap

Tags: python, pandas

I am working in a notebook, so if I run:

```
df1 = df1.join(series2)
```

It works fine. However, if I run it again, I receive the following error:

```
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified
```

Because it is equivalent to `df1 = df1.join(series2).join(series2)`. Is there any way I can force an overwrite on the overlapping columns without creating an endless amount of columns with the _y suffix?

Sample df1

```
index a
0     0
0     1
1     2    
1     3
2     4
2     5
```

Sample series2

```
index b
0     1
1     2
2     3
```

Desired output from `df1 = df1.join(series2)`

```
index a     b
0     0     1
0     1     1
1     2     2
1     3     2
2     4     3
2     5     3
```

Desired output from `df1 = df1.join(series2); df1 = df1.join(series2)`

```
# same as above because of forced overwrite on either the left or right join.
index a     b
0     0     1
0     1     1
1     2     2
1     3     2
2     4     3
2     5     3
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and output, please?

Comment: @Mushroomator I've added both. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide your desired output too, please

Comment: @AlexMontano I've added clarification that the desired result is that the operation are the bottom 2 code blocks.

Comment: What's the purpose of redoing the join? Is there some additional data you're trying to insert with it? If so, can you include that in your example?

Comment: @joanis Being able to redo the join without it throwing an error is just a workflow improvement when I'm working in a notebook and objects are preserved in memory. For example, if I have a cell with `df1["col"] = series2` this allows me to run the cell however many times I want if series2 changes. But if I need to join on the indices `df1 = df1.join(series2)` will fail if even if series2 changes due to column collision.

Comment: So if `series2` changes and then you re-run the join, you want `df1` to reflect the new values in `series2`. That makes sense.

Comment: Would it be easy to have that cell in your notebook first remove the colliding column from df1 if it exists, and then do the join? That would work whether the join had been done before or not.

Comment: I see, so something like `df1 = df1.drop(columns=series2.name, errors="ignore").join(series2)`. Seems a little verbose but I think that would work.